# The lead function in the R package dplyr is not working for me

Tags: r, dplyr, lead

```
library(dplyr)

x <- 1:10

lead(x)
```

Running the above code just gives me the following error:

"Error in UseMethod("lead") :
no applicable method for 'lead' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')""

I have tried a bunch of things like as.numeric and as.vector, but I'm consistently getting this error.

Comment: try with `dplyr::lead(x)`

Comment: @RonakShah thank you, it worked. Can you explain why I have to  specify dplyr:: ? Shouldn't R by default use this package?

Comment: It is because there is another package loaded that has `lead` function which is masking the `lead` function from `dplyr`.